# Retrive GCM registreation id but runtime error occure

Tags: android

1. import android.app.Activity;
                  import android.os.Bundle;
                  import android.util.Log;
                  import android.widget.TextView;
                  import static com.example.gcm_id.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;

   ```
              import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

              public class MainActivity extends Activity {
               private String TAG = "** pushAndroidActivity **";
               private TextView mDisplay;
               //static final String SENDER_ID ="628298704769";
               @Override
               public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                   checkNotNull(SENDER_ID,"SENDER_ID");
                   //Log.v(TAG, "GCMRegistrar");
                   GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
                   GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

                   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                   mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);


                   final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
                   Log.i(TAG, "registration id =====  "+regId);
                   if (regId.equals("")) 
                   {
                       GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
                   } 
                   else 
                   {
                       Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
                   }
                   mDisplay.setText("ffffff"+regId);
               }



               //          final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
               //          Log.i(TAG, "registration id =====  "+regId);
               //           
               //          if (regId.equals("")) {
               //          GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
               //          } else {
               //          Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
               //          }
               //           
               //          mDisplay.setText("ffffff "+regId);
               //      
               //      }

               private void checkNotNull(Object reference, String name) {
                   if (reference == null) {
                       throw new NullPointerException(getString(R.string.hello_world, name, name));

                   }
               }

               @Override
               protected void onPause() {
                   super.onPause();
                   GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
               }






              }











      GCMBaseintentservice:-

          package com.example.gcm_id;

          import android.content.Context;
          import android.content.Intent;
          import android.util.Log;
          import static com.example.gcm_id.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
          import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

          public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
           //static final String SENDER_ID = "628298704769";
           public GCMIntentService() {
               super(SENDER_ID);
           }

           private static final String TAG = "===GCMIntentService===";


           @Override
           protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId) {
               Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
           }

           @Override
           protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
               Log.i(TAG, "unregistered = "+arg1);
           }

           @Override
           protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
               Log.i(TAG, "new message= ");
           }

           @Override
           protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
               Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
           }

           @Override
           protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
               return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
           }

          }

      String KEY:=

      public final class CommonUtilities {

   static final String SENDER_ID = "628298704769";    }
   ```

   Error LOG_CAT OUTPUT

   10-01 13:11:33.897: D/AndroidRuntime(1473): Shutting down VM 10-01
   13:11:33.897: W/dalvikvm(1473): threadid=1: thread exiting with
   uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 10-01 13:11:33.967:
   E/AndroidRuntime(1473): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-01 13:11:33.967:
   E/AndroidRuntime(1473): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
   activity
   ComponentInfo{com.example.gcm_id/com.example.gcm_id.MainActivity}:
   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have
   package com.google.android.gsf 10-01 13:11:33.967:
   E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at
   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
   10-01 13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at
   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
   10-01 13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at
   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
   10-01 13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at
   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
   10-01 13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at
   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-01
   13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):   at
   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 10-01 13:11:33.967:
   E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at
   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 10-01
   13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):   at
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-01
   13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):   at
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 10-01 13:11:33.967:
   E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
   10-01 13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 10-01
   13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):   at
   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-01 13:11:33.967:
   E/AndroidRuntime(1473): Caused by:
   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have
   package com.google.android.gsf 10-01 13:11:33.967:
   E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at
   com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(GCMRegistrar.java:98)
   10-01 13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at
   com.example.gcm_id.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21) 10-01
   13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):   at
   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
   10-01 13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at
   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
   10-01 13:11:33.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     ... 11 more

Comment: You need to expain your issue when/how and give LogCat output.

Comment: if i comment this code  GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this)  code has been run.. but the registrationid not given ...

Comment: You still need to post the error output. It is impossible to guess the origin of the error otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the answer as it was all specific for my app, been to long since I worked with this.. i will wait for LogCat output instead

Answer (score 0):

Either you have the wrong target set for your project or your device does not have support for Google APIs. In the former case, Change Your Build Traget to one of the Google APIs (>= GOOGLE APIs 10). Its not working because your project couldn't find the Google Apis necessary for GCM to work. Right click your project, go to properties > Android and change the build target. If you dont have Google Apis installed, you will have to install it first through SDK Manager.

If your device does not support google apis e.g you might be testing it on an emulator with target set to Android Api and not Google Api; create a new emulator with target set to Google APIs (>=10)

[image]

[image]

Comment: i also use google api 17 but not running and not given the registration key

Comment: does your device has support for google api ? e.g you could be trying it on an emulator with target not set to google apis. if thats the case; create a new emulator with target set Google Apis (>= 10).